# Full page responsive container

Tags: html, css

I have 100% height and width container, then means if the resolution of the any screen is 100%, then the elements inside of the container is compressing if the resolution is not compatible in my *position design*, I want to have a responsive container with responsive elements inside of it but the elements will not compress. (Example try to resize the stackoverflow website, the elements is still the same.)

Here's my example code:

```css
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Container</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about what is actually needed, if you want to restrict the elements from not being responsive above or below a particular value, you need to fix the container element to a fixed pixel width when the width is less/greater than particular screen value using media queries.

Refer [CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

In the below JSFiddle you can see that the elements is set to fixed width (`500px`) when the screen width is less than 500px.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: thanks bro, one more thing what if, if the resolution is big, the pixel will be compatible again?

Comment: @pacificskybeachresort In the JSfiddle demo you can see that when we go to higher width than 500px, the responsive design works fine.